How do I make the horizontal scroll bar in a listbox be to the right when UserForm starts?
In Office 365, I have a list box in a userForm.

I changed the direction of the user form to be from right to left.
I want to make the horizontal scroll bar to be to the right when the user form starts.


Isn't it UserForm_Initialize // ListBox1.SetFocus, so you can focus on what is visible when you open a userform?  You can set the focus for a combobox, listbox, textbox, etc., which is to the right within your userform.

Please EDIT YOUR POST to include the script you've tried so we can assess if something may have been missing or erroneous in your trials.

Thank you for your interest , I am not an expert in Excel VBA, and I have tried many codes through the Internet or code writing sites(I've deleted the codes I tried that didn't work), so I hope to write a code that helps make the scroll bar start to the right.

UserForm_Initialize // ListBox1.SetFocus   dont work

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66565046/vba-cannot-set-righttoleft-even-with-excel-language-set-to-arabic .  I am unsure if it works for content within the listbox, but may be a step closer

The problem is not in my language settings, as my primary language is Arabic and all settings are perfectly fine , At one stage, I found a VBA code that the vertical scrolling cursor started from the bottom, but it did not help me to make the horizontal scrolling cursor start from the right.

This works for me but cannot test in 365.
What is essential that the end of the text cannot be a CR/LF because that set the cursor to the first position.
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.RightToLeft = True
text1 = "Here you can place any text only to check the final result" & Chr(10) & "of the position of the scroll bar" & Chr(10)
text2 = text1 & "Here you can place any text only to check the final result" & Chr(10) & "Here you can place any text only to check the final result" & Chr(10)
Me.TextBox1.Text = text2 & "Here you can place any text only to check the final result" & Chr(10) & "Here you can place any text only to check the final resultHere you can place any text only to check the final result"  'no CR/LF at the end.

End Sub




